# Java - int/long, float/double

Tags: java, floating-point, double, long-integer, primitive-types

I understand that "2.5" is automatically a double, and to make it a float, I need to do "2.5F" (or should the F be lowercase?), and that I should use a float, say, if I had a constant that only ever needed 2 decimal spaces (like "0.08F" for Ontario PST tax), but I'm not sure whether "12" is an int or a long, but I know "12L" is a long, but "long l = 12" and "long l = 12L" seem to compile to the same thing, and I use long's if I want maximum non-floating point precision, and int if I know I won't need beyond int's limits.

Please correct me if there's something there that isn't right, and answer the quesions I have.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

12 as a constant in java is an int.

The reason long l = 12 compiles is that it is automatically widened to a long.

EDIT: Regarding your comment, there is nothing wrong with automatic widening, use whatever makes your code clearer, but just be aware of what is going on when you do math on primitives. For example:

```
int i = 1213;
long l = 112321321L * i;
```

The long will have a very different value if you don't explicitly put that first number as a long because Java will treat it as integer math, and cause an overflow.

Comment: Should I put the L in anyway or just let it automatically widen?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the automatic widening, use whatever makes your code clearer.

Answer (score 7):

It doesn't make a difference if you use lower or upper case when declaring your `float`s .

> ...like "0.08F" for Ontario PST tax

If you are using these fields for currency, you should consider using [`BigDecimal`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) instead.  [See this explanation](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) and its related links from Sun for more detail.

Comment: +1. Please please don't use floating point numbers for currencies, EVER

Comment: Working in the financial industry, writing software for financial institutions, I agree.  In fact, I try and avoid doubles where ever possible, even in places where the precision is not that important - unless I need the speed, I would prefer having too much precision than not enough :)

Comment: I was using separate longs to represent currencies, but apparently I should have been using BigDecimal, anyway.

Answer (score 3):

First, 12 is an `int`.  Since you didn't specify a type, the compiler assumes `int`, just as it assumes `double` when you don't specify a type for 2.5.

The assignment

```
long x = 12;
```

compiles just fine because there is no loss of precision when the compiler implicitly upcasts the literal `int` value 12 to a `long`.

I always try to use uppercase type specifiers like 2.5F and 12L, simply because they're easier to read.  1 and l look much the same in the monospaced font that I prefer.

Answer (score 3):

Note that while `int` literals will be auto-widened to `long` when assigning to a `long` variable, you will need to use an explicit `long` literal when expressing a value that is greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (2147483647) or less than `Integer.MIN_VALUE` (-2147483648):

```
long x1 = 12; //OK
long x2 = 2147483648; // not OK! That's not a valid int literal
long x3 = 2147483648L; // OK
```